# Ошибки при сборке проект на Nest.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, backend, nest.js

Есть проект на фреймворке ***Nest.js***. Так вот, локально (Windows) всё работает хорошо, могу собрать что в *production*, что в *dev* моде. Но когда я перекидываю и начинаю сборку проекта на сервере на **Ubuntu**, то у меня вылезает огромная куча ошибок компиляции ***Typescript***.

[image: Начало сборки]

[image: Кучи ошибок]

[image: Package.json]

tsconfig.json

[image: tsconfig.json]

Comment: А как вы перекидывали проект на сервер?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, Через гит репозиторий

Comment: Переустановка npm пакетов не помогла? Не пробовали?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, пробовал, и версию typescript мотал по разным, и сам проект удалял и заного пуллил, не помогло

Comment: Щас ещё добавлю package.json в вопрос, может что-то даст